# apache2 / webmin confusion, who's gonna handle request?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I have a machine that is running apache and webmin, webmin is based on a lightweight web server called miniserv.pl
Typing my.server.url/phpmyadmin/ I reach the phpmyadmin but this is pretty strange because I dont have any phpmyadmin in my `/var/www` neither any virtualhost that handle that url. So this miniserv.pl is gonna handle that request, but this pretty confuse, how can a request on port 80 be handled by this miniserv.pl instead of apache?
Could anyone clarify this to me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin web files are generally stored in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` not in /var/www. So you need to check that directory. If it is being served by Apache, you will find the Apache configuration file for phpMyAdmin in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` with an Alias directive - eg.

```
   Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: oh man that's right thanks I should had check for all includes....